# How to Check Kafka Lag into topics for kafka version 2.11-0.11.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I used kafka version 2.10-0.9.0.1, all information goes to zookeeper so i used the following command to checke kafka Lag:

> ./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group
>   group-name --topic topicName --zookeeper  zooIp:2181

Now we used latest kafka version 2.11-0.11.0.0, here this command not works.
How we see the kafka lag of topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsets are not stored anymore in Zookeeper but directly in Kafka now.

You can use the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool (`kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand`) to retrieve the position/lag of a group.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server KAFKA_HOST:KAFKA_PORT --describe --group GROUP_NAME
```